# Attribute does not save and always shows nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ancestry

I have an object that contains the column, `parent_id` which is an integer

I just ran this migration just to start fresh

```
class RemoveParentIdFromCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :categories, :parent_id, :integer
    add_column :categories, :parent_id, :integer
  end
end
```

When I go to console...I run

```
c = Category.all.last
c.parent_id = 5
c.save
```

and c displays:

```
#<Category id: 29, name: "Example", parent_id: nil, ancestry: "1/2/4/5", created_at: "2015-05-21 20:45:12", updated_at: "2015-05-21 23:30:50", is_main: nil, color: "ffffff", cached_name: "mets">
```

I am using the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry):

I have the following validations

```
  has_ancestry
  has_many :topic, :foreign_key => 'category_id'
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :ancestry
```

I want to use the `parent_id` to check uniqueness for a search, but I cant since I unfortunately can't save it.

Why can't I save anything to `parent_id`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there is a category record with id 5?

Comment: Yes there is. (i just rechecked). Also, the ancestry gem is working perfectly, and I was pulling the last id from that column each time I tried to save it.

Comment: Does the console show any sql being executed when you do `c.save`? You may need to execute `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in the console first to see it.

Comment: Why are you adding and removing the same column in the same migration? If you want to start fresh just rollback.

Comment: Try `c.save!`. See if it throws any validation errors.

Comment: attr_accessor :parent_id by any chance?

Comment: check any before_save callback which reset parent_id...

Comment: thank you though c.save! shed light on the answer..dont know why i didnt try that :\  There was a validation issue, I was saving the parent_id as the same id as the category `Validation failed: Category cannot be a descendant of itself.`